# How to save the n-d numpy array data and read it quickly next time?

Tags: python, numpy

#### Here is my question:

I have a 3-d numpy array Data which in the shape of (1000, 100, 100).
And I want to save it as a .txt or .csv file, how to achieve that?

My first attempt was to reshape it into a 1-d array which length 1000*100*100, and transfer it into pandas.Dataframe, and then, I save it as .csv file.

When I wanted to call it next time,I would reshape it back to 3-d array.

I think there must be some methods easier.

Comment: You may want to have a look at `np.save` and `np.savetxt`

Comment: Reshape is cheap.  Convert to/from text more expensive.  Pandas has a faster loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to re-read it quickly into `numpy` you could just use the `cPickle` module.

This is going to be much faster that parsing it back from an ASCII dump (but however only the program will be able to re-read it). As a bonus with just one instruction you could dump more than a single matrix (i.e. any data structure built with core python and `numpy` arrays).

Note that parsing a floating point value from an ASCII string is a quite complex and slow operation (if implemented correctly down to ulp).

Comment: No point in using `cPickle` when numpy has a host of binary save/load options. See [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/routines.io.html).